# wordpress or jquery a dynamic photo gallery

Tags: plugins

i'm working on a simple wordpress site and i would like to create a dynamic fancy photo gallery.

I have seen this type of photos galleries on some sites, to be more precisely i want to have the same effect like in this video on 30 seconds :

https://www.facebook.com/Freekerstudio/videos/vb.434383593291961/942401725823476/?type=2&theater

this can be a jquery plugin or a wordpress plugin.

Any advice is welcome, thank you in advance for your time and help Mike.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for a plugin that applies **masonry layout** on your photos.

When selecting appropriate WP plugin keep in mind that you presumably want one that gives you whole *gallery functionality*  (lightbox, [lazy-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274/what-is-lazy-loading) or pagination etc.)

Free version of this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-bank/) seems to have at least some of these.

As for jQuery plugin, if your project is not commercial (or if it is and you don't mind spending a few dollars), I recommend using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). It's as simple to work with as using jQuery function on a container of your photos. It is also offering nice filtering features, fancy effects and full responsiveness.